# Filtering Pandas Dataframe using OR statement over a list of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a dataframe according to whether any of several columns in a list match a test.

E.g., it can work in this way:

```
ddf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
ddf[(ddf['A']==0)|(ddf['B']==0)|(ddf['C']==0)|(ddf['D']==0)]
```

...and one could build a loop if there are many more columns to process. But I wonder whether there's a more pythonic way to proceed, starting from the result of

```
ddf[list('ABCD')]==0
```

which gives 4 columns of booleans, over which I'd like to apply a `or` operation by row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the same test like whether it is zero, then you use `any()` across the rows:

```
np.random.seed(999)
ddf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

ddf[(ddf[['A','B','C','D']]==0).any(axis=1)]

     A   B   C   D
71  52  13   0  50
93  51   0  60  71
```